# Persistent shell-command history

Tags: shell-command, session

When I run [`shell-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html) in a new session I do not have access to the history of commands from the last session. How can I have that?

Comment: do you have `(savehist-mode)` enabled?

Comment: If you are talking about `M-!`, the history variable it reads/writes from is `shell-command-history`, which is covered with `(savehist-mode)`. If the request is about keeping a persistent history of the `comint-input-ring` in shell buffers, I can assist with that too, but from how i'm interpreting the question, this would accomplish it.

Comment: @waymondo no, I did not. solves my problem. Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is enable [`(savehist-mode)`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SaveHist) in your .emacs. This will save all minibuffer history rings by default, which includes `shell-command-history` which is used by `M-!` / `(shell-command)`.

---

While I'm at it, I figure I'll also explain how to load/save command histories from `shell-mode` prompts and other modes that derive from `comint-mode`.

Note: this is for my setup with bash and OSX, but the guts of this should work in most environments.

- First you need to copy your bash shell history into your emacs' environment. By default this is stored in a variable called "HISTFILE". I do this with the [`(exec-path-from-shell)`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package like so:

  ```
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "HISTFILE")
  ```
- Then you need to call `(turn-on-comint-history)` in your appropriate mode hooks, i.e.

  ```
  (defun turn-on-comint-history (history-file)
            (setq comint-input-ring-file-name history-file)
            (comint-read-input-ring 'silent))

  (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (turn-on-comint-history (getenv "HISTFILE"))))

  (add-hook 'inf-ruby-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (turn-on-comint-history ".pry_history")))
  ```

For interactive ruby modes, you can see I'm using a local `.pry_history` file on a per-project basis.

- Then you need to make sure you save your comint history files when killing buffers and emacs:

  ```
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'comint-write-input-ring)
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            (lambda ()
              (--each (buffer-list)
                (with-current-buffer it (comint-write-input-ring)))))
  ```

Note I am using [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) for the succinct `(--each)` formatting.

This will make your minibuffer shell command history persistent as well as your bash prompt command history between emacs and other terms.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that `savehist` can manage this, here is my setup:

```
;; Save sessions history
(setq savehist-save-minibuffer-history 1)
(setq savehist-additional-variables
      '(kill-ring search-ring regexp-search-ring compile-history log-edit-comment-ring)
      savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/savehist")
(savehist-mode t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can advice `shell-command` to save history and remap some related key bindings, e.g., `M-n/p`, for invoking that history, or even write your own `shell-command` by using `read-from-minibuffer` if you like.